# How to keep running a nested While in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, pygame

### I have a pygame. in it there are a few nested while loops, running all of them one time accomplish one round, how do I keep rounds going and going, never stop?

**Repeat**{I have a pygame. in it there are a few nested while loops, running all of them one time accomplish one round, how do I keep rounds going and going, never stop? I have a pygame. in it there are a few nested while loops, running all of them one time accomplish one round, how do I keep rounds going and going, never stop? I have a pygame. in it there are a few nested while loops, running all of them one time accomplish one round, how do I keep rounds going and going, never stop? I have a pygame. in it there are a few nested while loops, running all of them one time accomplish one round, how do I keep rounds going and going, never stop? }**Repeat**

```
def running_game():
    import pygame
    pygame.init()
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    robot = pygame.image.load("robot.png")


    x = 0
    y = 0
    velocity = 5
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
        window.blit(robot, (x, y))
        pygame.display.flip()
        print(x)
        x += velocity
        if x+robot.get_width() >= 640:
            #break
            #print(x)
            while True:
                window.fill((0, 0, 0))
                window.blit(robot, (x, y))
                pygame.display.flip()
                y += velocity
                #clock.tick(60)
                if y+robot.get_height() >= 480:
                    #break
                    velocity = -velocity
                    while True:
                        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
                        window.blit(robot, (x, y))
                        pygame.display.flip()
                        x += velocity
                        if x <= 0:
                            #break
                            while True:
                                window.fill((0, 0, 0))
                                window.blit(robot, (x, y))
                                pygame.display.flip()
                                y += velocity
                                if y <= 0:
                                    velocity = -velocity
                                    break               

        clock.tick(120)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True: 
        running_game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too much nesting there. Because all the inner `while` loops never terminate, the program also never gets back to the `pygame.event.get()` call, which is why you'll also find that the program doesn't respond to input (including closing the window). There is also a lot of duplicated code.

It's better to keep the robot's current direction in a variable, let's call it `direction`, and change the value of that when it reaches the edge. To make the code easier to understand, you can define some constants at the top:

```
UP = 0
RIGHT = 1
DOWN = 2
LEFT = 3

def running_game():
    import pygame
    pygame.init()
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    robot = pygame.image.load("robot.png")

    x = 0
    y = 0
    velocity = 5
    direction = RIGHT
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()

        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
        window.blit(robot, (x, y))
        pygame.display.flip()

        if direction == UP:
            y -= velocity
            if y <= 0:
                direction = RIGHT
        elif direction == RIGHT:
            x += velocity
            if x+robot.get_width() >= 640:
                direction = DOWN
        elif direction == DOWN:
            y += velocity
            if y+robot.get_height() >= 480:
                direction = LEFT
        elif direction == LEFT:
            x -= velocity
            if x <= 0:
                direction = UP

        clock.tick(120)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True: 
        running_game()
```